# Specifying option label (listValue) with Struts Select tag

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

listValue attribute of the  tag is used to specify the label that should display to user when selecting that option.

Example -

```
<s:select name="user" list='users' listValue="username" listKey="userId"
label="Select an User" />
```

Is it possible to do the same when enumerating the list with an OGNL literal?

```
<s:select name="distance" cssClass="textBoxStyle" headerValue="Select Distance"
 headerKey="" list="{'1 Km', '2 Km', '3 Km', '5 Km', '8 Km', '12 Km', '20 Km'}" />
```

I want the 1Km to be displayed to the user and integer 1 not string 1Km to be submitted with the form.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a raw array like the one you have coded, you should consider getting a Map from the Action which lies behind this view. In that case, the Map in the Action will look like:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("1 Km", 1);
...
```

and the code in the view will be:

```
<s:select name="distance" cssClass="textBoxStyle" headerValue="Select Distance"
    headerKey="" list="myMap" />
```

with the keys of the map being viewed as labels, and the values as the option bodies.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use the `listKey` and `listValue` attributes, and build an actual list of objects.

Technically you could probably do some perverse OGNL, and you could certainly do it via JavaScript and a hidden field pre-submit, but as the other answer states, you're better off doing it in the Java layer rather than the view layer.

I disagree with the other answer in that a list of objects seems more communicative, and easy to build, but from a technical standpoint there's no difference in this case, so it's more a matter of opinion.